# Rails - Rspec throws an exception on expect.to.eq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Trying to do a simple assert using rspec on an integer, and it keeps failing with the following exception. Any idea what the problem is?

Logs show that the count has been incremented

```
it 'Should add the new message as attendee' do
  message_count = user.messages.count
  pp (user.messages.count)
  post :add_message, { user_id: user.id}
  pp (user.messages.count)
  # I also tried equal
  expect(user.messages.count).to eq(message_count+1)
end


Failure/Error: expect(user.messages.count).to eq(message_count+1)
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)
```

Comment: Does the stacktrace say that it fails on the line containing `expect`, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have a typo in this line (coun **t**)?

```
expect(user.messages.coun).to eq(message_count+1)
```

Comment: Ughh , sorry that was a typo in the question, the actual code is correct